# Python Convert binary String to binary int

Tags: python, python-2.7

I use the following function to convert an int number to become binary. While adding additional zeros (16 bit). But the result comes in binary string, which creates problems for me when I use it in an if statement with "Bitwise left-shifting and bitwise AND operator".

```
def binary(num, length=16):
            return format(num, '#0{}b'.format(length + 2))
```

The function used in context:

```
if (binary(1024) & (1<<2)):
    print "Bit 2 is SET"
```

But get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "log.py", line 209, in <module>
    if (binary(1024) & (1<<2)):
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'
```

Simply explained:

```
"0b0000010000000000" to be: 0b0000010000000000
```

Are there any simple solutions to this?

Comment: Do you mean - `int(binary_string, 2)` (passing in the base) ?

Comment: try `if (1024 & (1<<2)):`, your binary method is useless. masks work all right with integers. integers _are_ binary after all...

Comment: why even explicity convert to binary if you're just using bitwise `& `anyway? That always works on binary bit-level regardless of input format.

Comment: I actually switch 1024 and bit 2 with variables.
But removed this to try to make it easier to understand the example.

if (binary(getattr(data, alarm['alarmTag'])) & (1<<int(alarm['alarmBit']))):

Comment: Oh, I understand now. Removed the entire binary function and used int() instead in the if statement.

It worked fine, thank you. Zinki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When ever you use any bitwise operators on a number , it automatically applies it as we would usually visualize the operation being performed on a binary value .

In your case , you can simply convert the string to integer first and then if u want you can also get the binary representation of the same number using the `bin( )` function which returns a string in the binary represention.

**Here is the code :-**

```
numstring = "15"

num_in_base_10 = int(numstring)
string_in_binary_form = bin(num_in_base10)

#If you dont want the 0b prefix of the binary repr , you can simple do , 

string_in_binary_form.replace('0b','') which would return the string without 0b prefix.
```